# Lightning Components Badge

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-apps, package-install, lightning-components

I need help to solve this problem:

I'm trying to complete the Lighting App Builder Trail... So, I'm doing the last challenge
where ask me:
[image]

So, when I'm going install package tab and paste it the Package ID copied in the requirements, displays me this error! I don't understand why...

[image: "Enter a valid ID fot the app or package you want to install"]

Comment: Considering the "Note", are you using a playground org?

Comment: Is there not a blank before "04t..."? Make sure there are no blanks in the beginning and in the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there not a blank before "04t..."? Make sure there are no blanks in the beginning and in the end.

@Felix van Hove